# Common views in viewControllers - Code re-usability

Tags: iphone, ios

I have few common views in most of my **viewControllers**. What I noticed is that I can reuse single code for all **viewControllers** which is absolutely wise. For this I decided to create a class **Utils** which has static methods like

```
+(void)createCommonViews:(float)yAxis:(NSString*)text;
```

In my case common views are three labels and two images.

**Problem** : I am not able to add these views from **Utils**. I am wondering how can I send self as a parameter so that I may add the views from Utils. It may be wrong to add views outside the viewController. In that case what can be the solution? Taking all these views in a `UIView`, setting return type of **Utils** method as `UIView` and then adding `UIView` to **viewController** (after calling method from **viewController**) might solve my problem. But what I am looking for is some **other** solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+(void) createCommonViews:(float)yAxis withText:(NSString*) text toTarget:(UIViewController*) target
{
//create views
    [target addSuview:view];
}
```

But I think returning a Uiview and then adding it in the UIViewController afterwards, is a far better solution.

Answer (score 1):

The method you're attempting is to have your view object as a singleton. This is uncommon at best, at worst a crash waiting to happen. Better design is for each of your view controller classes to have its own instance of your custom view, like so:

```
@interface MyCommonView : UIView

// ...

@end



@interface MyViewController_A : UIViewController {
   MyCommonView *commonView;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MyCommonView *commonView;

@end



// Meanwhile somewhere else...



@interface MyViewController_B : UIViewController {
   MyCommonView *commonView;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MyCommonView *commonView;

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a viewController that acts as a parent view for all your common stuff, call it CommonViewController then implement this in all the viewcontrollers you want it to appear

```
-(void) viewDidLoad 
{
   [self.view addSubView:[[CommonViewController alloc] initWithRect:..];
}
```

Or alternatively using xib files